# Parse XML: Get child nodes for each parent node

Tags: php, xml, parsing, nodes, treenode

I tried a lot of different solutions but I'm just new at this..

I have an xml tree like this:

```
<book>
  <author> First author </author>
  <title> aaaa </title>
  <price> 111 </price>
</book>
<book>
  <author> Second author </author>
  <title> bbbb </title>
  <price> 222 </price>
</book>
<book>
  <author> Third author </author>
  <title> cccc </title>
  <price> 333 </price>
</book>`
```

I need to parse it in my php code to obtain a table such as

```
First author,
aaaa,
111

Second author,
bbbb,
222

Third author,
cccc,
333
```

Is it possible?
Really thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you had a look at [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class to parse your xml, *notice* that the xml needs to be valid:

```
// create a DOMDocument object and load your xml data
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xmlString);

// get all book sections
$books = $doc->getElementsByTagName('book');

// loop through each item and display information
foreach ($books as $book) {
    print $book->getElementsByTagName('author')->item(0)->nodeValue . ',<br />';
    print $book->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue . ',<br />';
    print $book->getElementsByTagName('price')->item(0)->nodeValue . '<br /><br />';
}
```

To load the xml data from a file you could use [`DOMDocument::load()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php)

A simpler way to do the same would be to use [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php):

```
// create a SimpleXMLElement
$xmlDoc = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);

// get all children of the first element
$books = $xmlDoc->children();

// loop through each item and display information
foreach ($books as $book) {
    print $book->author . ',<br />';
    print $book->title . ',<br />';
    print $book->price . '<br /><br />';
}
```

Notice that the second example will only work if your xml is considered to be well formed, you could wrap your current markup between `<books></books>`:

```
<books>
  <book>
    <author> First author </author>
    <title> aaaa </title>
    <price> 111 </price>
 </book>
 ...
</books>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, that worked. I was already trying to use DOMDocument but I was missing something.
Just one question for my understandind: the variable $key is it there for what? I don't get this passage.

Comment: I adjusted the code to get more nodes.. But I really don't understand the "as $key" part, that was the one missing in my other attempts that infact, failed. There is a source that I can study better?

Comment: You shouldn't need to use the `$key` in your loop. Should work fine without it. I edited my answer and added another way to do the same thing.

Comment: Sorry the second code print just the ",<br />", but not the values of the nodes.

Comment: @Rain_xx - Works fine for me, are you sure you have a valid xml markup? Does it contain a root element?

Comment: @Rain_xx - You need to have root element - you could wrap your current xml between `<books></books>` to get the second example working. Since no root element exists your xml is considered to be **not** well formed.